# Why OpenShift V3 can't visit the java website outside with its sub domain?

Tags: docker, openshift

In past time I had use the openshift platform v3 deploy my some demo research things, and it work fine and can visit through outside domain which build under openshift itself.

But recently it can't visit with outside domain, it looks strange. And I sure the docker service is running status(As openshift call it pods). Also it can login terminal with cli command. And check the openshift server status is OK. Some screenshot like below attachments.

I had try all ways I known. But not any effected. Why? Is there someone can help me resolve it? Thanks.

[image: application is not available]
[image: server running status]
[image: cli output message]

Comment: If you were using ``ca-central-1`` try again. There was an issue with restoring routes when applications were un-idled. It is believed this has been fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had retry project build and get work fine. Others do you known how to upgrade the memory limit by default not use cli way, just change on WEB UI.

Comment: OK, I had found the way change the limited. But new question is coming. How cant I set custom domain forward to my app? Remember that my account in free plan.

Comment: You can't use a custom domain name for the route in OpenShift Starter, only Pro tier allows that. Remember that Starter is for experimentation only, not permanent sites. Is there a reason you need a custom domain name given it would only be for testing?

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, I had try a REST API server test for other 3rd customer. But the customer had some limited about the domain level. So that is my problem. No matter what thanks openshift give us a usefully platform. Thanks.